# Python regex to parse the datetime.datetime object from string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
"{'foo': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 23, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'bar': 'some data', 'foobar': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 3, 13, 57, 41, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'barlist': ['hello', 'world']}"
```

I want to be able to match all the `datetime.datetime(...)` strings within this string and replace it with the numbers in a list form only. So this is the expected result:

```
"{'foo': [2022, 5, 23, 0, 0], 'bar': 'some data', 'foobar': [2022, 8, 3, 13, 57, 41], 'barlist': ['hello', 'world']}"
```

I have something like this:

```
DATETIME_PATTERN = r"datetime.datetime\(((\d+)(,\s*\d+)*), tzinfo=.*\)"
modified_input_str = re.sub(DATETIME_PATTERN, r"[\1]", input_str)
```

but it replaces a big chunk of data inbetween the matches. How can I modify the regex to accomplish what I want?

Conclusion:
I made a modification of the current best answer so it fits my particular usecase more:

```py
DATETIME_PATTERN = r"datetime\.datetime\((\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*), tzinfo=(?:[^\s\d])*\)"

# The difference is that the string at the end of 'tzinfo=' can be anything but whitespace or numbers.
```

Comment: Please add the required language tag.  Not all regex engines are created equal.

Comment: Added the python tag and mentioned in the title!

Comment: It [looks to be working well](https://regex101.com/r/pqeMic/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oops sorry I accidentally added indents to the mock data which worked for this pattern. Just removed the newlines so it reflects more closely with the data I'm working with!

Comment: What about `datetime\.datetime\(((\d+)(,\s*\d+)*), tzinfo=(?:\(\)|[^()])*\)`? Do you expect anything inside the parentheses?

Comment: Whoa that worked, thanks! The type of text after `tzinfo=` could be any letter/special character that are NOT spaces or numbers.

Comment: this looks close to output from displaying a Python dict - is it possible to have the datetimes output as epoch timestamps instead by the source? https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp

Comment: @ti7 I actually want to convert it back to datetime objects so I can then call `.isoformat()` on the object to store in our system. Can we do that without first converting it to datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
datetime\.datetime\((\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*), tzinfo=(?:\(\)|[^()])*\)
```

*Details*:

- `datetime\.datetime\(` - a `datetime.datetime(` string
- `(\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*)` - Group 1: one or more digits and then zero or more repetitions of a comma + zero or more whitespaces and then one or more digits
- `, tzinfo=` - a literal string
- `(?:\(\)|[^()])*` - zero or more repetitions of a `()` string or any char other than `(` and `)`
- `\)`  - a `)` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pqeMic/3).